# how to store multiple encoded values in multiple variables

Tags: javascript, html

I have given multiple upload file option but it is storing everything in one variable but i am not getting how to store seperate file encoded value in a seperate variable. It should create variable and store encoded value according to file upload.

```
<html>
<body>

<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" multiple />
<div id="imgTest"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function encodeImageFileAsURL(index) {
        var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
        index = index || 0;
        if (filesSelected.length > 0 && index < filesSelected.length) {
            var fileToLoad = filesSelected[index];

            var fileReader = new FileReader();

            fileReader.onloadend = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

                var newImage = document.createElement('img');
                newImage.src = srcData;

                document.getElementById("imgTest").appendChild(newImage);
                if (index < filesSelected.length) {
                    encodeImageFileAsURL(index + 1)
                }
                console.log(srcData);    
            }
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may save the variable into an array, then access it whenever you want.

```
    var sourceArray = new Array(); // put this before the function delaction 


                fileReader.onloadend = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
                    var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

                    sourceArray.push(srcData);

                    var newImage = document.createElement('img');
                    newImage.src = srcData;

                    document.getElementById("imgTest").appendChild(newImage);
                    if (index < filesSelected.length) {
                        encodeImageFileAsURL(index + 1)
                    }}

                    console.log(sourceArray);
```

Comment: there is a missed } brackets , also add the array declaration outside the function ,
I tried and it works fines @user5397448

Comment: @user5397448 so you did not push the srcData into the array. 
sourceArray.push(srcData);
it is so direct and simple .

Comment: Easy approach nice one